# Proof of the Hardy-Littlewood Tauberian theorem

Tags: calculus, analysis

Can someone point me to a proof of the Hardy-Littlewood Tauberian theorem, that is suitable enough to be shown to high school students? (with knowledge of calculus, sequences and series of course)

Comment: Why should high-school students  bother about Tauberian theorems? Ask 100 professional mathematicians what Tauberian theorems are all about, and you will get $\leq1$ usable response.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you looked at the presentation in Titchmarsh's *Theory of Functions* (Section 7.5)? The only non-elementary part of the argument is Weierstrass's approximation theorem, which you can probably assume as a fact. The preliminary material given also include an "easy" special case where the exposition certainly can be understood by someone with knowledge of calculus, sequences, and series.

Comment: Unfortunately, I've been unable to get a hold of a copy of Titchmarsh's book so far.

Comment: It is available on [the Internet Archive](http://archive.org/details/TheTheoryOfFunctions).

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at Chapter 1, sections 11 and 12 of 
[*Tauberian Theory: A Century of Development*](http://books.google.ca/books/about/Tauberian_theory.html?id=Kh_nJe1ZWDoC) by Jacob Korevaar. 
He also has many references.